# How can i know which class was selected via jQuery & JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with links:

```
<li class="link-1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li class="link-2"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li class="link-3"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
..
```

user clicks on any link, then with jQuery I want to display the content of the link.. somthing like:

```
$(".link-??? a").click(function() {
    alert($(".link-??? a").html());
})
```

something like this. I am not going to create X function (as the number of the links), so what can I do? I should replace the `???` in somtehing else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do:

```
 $('li[class^="link"] a').click(...
```

However this would only work if the `li` have only one class or if the `link-X` class is the first in the list.

Inside the handler you can use `$(this)` to refer to the `a` element:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

**Much better** would be  to give the `li` elements a common class:

```
<li class="link"><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li class="link"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li class="link"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
```

`$('.link a').click(...` will be much more reliable.

Comment: I have never hear about `$(this)` (well.. i'm learning just a day :-)), it will solve the problem (with common class).

Comment: @Luis: Maybe you should read a tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery Basically, inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element the event originated (in this case the link). You can also pass DOM elements to jQuery, not only selectors, and that's what `$(this)` is about.

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
$(".link-??? a").click(function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
})
```

Inside the click event, `this` should refer to the element that was clicked.

You could also do..

```
alert($(this).html());
```

..but the first way is simpler, and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Give each element the same class.  Then in your javascript reference this within your function.  **Check out the link below to see a working example**

http://jsfiddle.net/kprgr/2/

```
<li class="link"><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li class="link"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li class="link"><a href="#">Three</a></li>

$(".link").click(function() {
    alert($(this).find("a").html());
});
```